# Locating an Element within an object design with javascript

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code I was using to at least select an element from the object. The image attached shows what the object look like on the web page. There is no unique name for me to use in selecting the object. With this code, I was able to see the seat count, but applying the click action on any of the seats did not work. Any idea in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
public static void SeatSelection()
{
    IList<IWebElement> seats = Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("circle"));
    foreach (IWebElement seat in seats)
    {
        if (seat.Displayed && seat.Enabled == true)
        {
            seat.Click();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tickets Sold Out");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Html code]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: can you try to install this plugin for firefox to help you find the xpath of the element you are looking for https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/try-xpath/?src=api

Comment: A link to the actual page would be really helpful. It's hard to tell what is supposed to be clickable from the HTML provided.